# Engine and ABS warning signs because of low battery?

Tags: ignition, warning-light

Two days ago, the "Engine warning sensors" and "ABS sensors" started blinking in my SUV, and the car was not starting (no ignition).  But the headlight, and AC was working fine.  After multiple trials, after 15 mins car finally started and I took it to the service center.

They told me that it is because of the low battery and everything is fine.  If battery was down, how come headlights and AC works but not the ignition ?.  I have a feeling that the service center guys are missing something.
Is it possible that ignition stops working because of low battery but headlight and AC works ?

Answer (score 1):

A low battery can be the cause of spurious signals ... charge it or replace it, clear any codes and test again.

My car is notorious for showing fake codes when the battery is low - it loves a battery that is in good condition and well charged...

Comment: To add to what Mike is saying; I accidentally left the radio playing on our 2012 VW which flattened the battery.  After trying to start it and finding it didn't have enough charge to start the car, we bump started it.  After that pretty much every fault light was illuminated.  Once the battery was fully charged, all the faults self-cleared.  Bear in mind most systems use resistance and voltage drop to assess vehicle health.  A low battery will lead to all kinds of false-positives